# Laravel 4 - Using renameColumn in controller

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, laravel-4, database-migration

I want to use artisan migration within my controller, like this

```
echo '<br>init migrate:install...';
Artisan::call('migrate');
echo 'done migrate:install';
```

It works fine for all my table creations and etc. But there are problems when I try to use $table->renameColumn

Laravel doc said I need to include doctrine/dbal, but how? I have tried `use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver;` but no luck.

FYI i cannot use CLI, my host doesn't provide any CLI to me.

**Here is my error**

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found
```

**UPDATE**

Same error when using terminal to migrate

**SECOND UPDATE**

An Example of migration code at app/database/migrations

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class UpdatePostsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('user', function($table)
        {
            $table->renameColumn('fullname', 'full_name');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to run it normaly in a terminal?

Comment: @DennisBraga Cannot. same error i receive. any idea?

Comment: Post your migration code, plz.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the `doctrine/dbal` dependency to your `composer.json` file.

For more information, it's on the very bottom of this page in the documentation.

http://laravel.com/docs/releases

Comment: If you are like me and didn't know exactly how to add this dependency here's a link to the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413408/install-dependency-doctrine-dbal-on-composer-laravel

Comment: Add <b>doctrine/dbal</b> dependency to your composer.json file

Answer (score 3):

Add **doctrine/dbal** dependency to your composer.json file, like

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "illuminate/html": "5.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.3"
},
```

Then update composer using **sudo composer update** command, this will work.

Comment: great answers as well, Please refer to accepted answer.