# Install dependency (doctrine/dbal) on composer laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to execute a migration to rename some columns and I got an exception.

As I read on the documentation I have to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to my composer.json file. How do I do that? Which is the correct composer.json file. I have many in my application. Is the one that is on the same level as the folders app,bootstrap, public and vendor.

If so how do I add that dependency. Do I have to download anything?

By the way im using easyphp, not wamp!

### Edit 1

After doing that the console throws this error

[image: cmd]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To add this dependency open the composer.json at the root of your project (in the same level as app, public etc.) and in the require section add the doctrine/dbal package like:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "v2.4.2"
},
```

Save the file and run `composer update`

**Edit**

You probably installed git with the default settings and it's not in your PATH env.

Open Git Bash (it was installed with git - you will find it in your programs) and do `composer update`. By the way it's far better that windows command prompt.

Comment: Won't `composer update` cause updates to every package in composer.json and overwriting composer.lock? I prefer using only `composer install` to be safe because I have experienced things going terribly wrong after blindly calling `composer update`.

Comment: @JustAMartin If you explicitly set the version numbers in composer.json, then those won't/shouldn't update. If you set it like above (4.1.*) then that will update to 4.1.9 and stop updating. if you just use a version number like (2.4.2) then it should never update (but will install if not already) This is in theory, I've never had a reason to worry since I'm using the latest version of everything atm, but in the past I know there were major changes between versions so I can understand where problems would arise.

Comment: composer require is the right answer here, so you won't have to fiddle around with version numbers/updates

Comment: After i install, when i run `php artisan migrate` its showing error `In AbstractPlatform.php line 423:
Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.`

Answer (score 166):

1) To install dependency , run this command

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

2) For 'git' is not recognized error, either you don't have git installed or the PATH is not added in the environment variables.

[Install git for windows](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-on-Windows).

Comment: This should be the answer. It auto adds it with the correct version to `composer.json`

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting error while running migration try this

```
composer require doctrine/dbal:2.*
```